# In dataflow, when column/rows are removed from table then does dataflow (PRO license, shared capacity) refresh perform query folding?

Tags: powerbi

In a dataflow (PRO license, shared capacity) when I remove certain columns or filter certain rows in a table, then during refresh does dataflow perform query folding by sending the appropriate modified query to data sources?

Or does dataflow fetch all data and then perform the deletion of column/row filtering at each refresh?